# symfony2 - form with date field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a problem with a symfony form and a date field. When I view the field, the value retrieved from the database is subtracted a day when it is rendered as a widget single_text and I can not fix it.

For the project I use Symfony 2.6Beta for Bootstrap form support.

The field in form is defined:

```
$builder->add('natoIl', 'birthday', array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'empty_value' => '',
    'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    'model_timezone' => 'Europe/Rome',
    'view_timezone' => 'Europe/Rome'
));
```

I have this problem with MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Thank you very much

EDIT:
The problem occurs only with the 'widget' option set to "single_text". I need to see it as text input to add a datepicker field.

EDIT #2:

Doing various tests I found that the problem is when I work with the PHP web server. PHP version I use is 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 PC with linux mint.

Comment: Are you missing the final single-quote in your code, or just in this example?

Comment: Just in this example... I have updated it.

Comment: Does the date is correct on the server?

Comment: Yes,it is...it's correct also default timezone in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to set your view and/or model timezone appropriately:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#view-timezone

Comment: I have tried to set `view_timezone` and `model_timezone` options but it doesn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug already fixed. The solution is then upgrading symfony.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12808